# Output AES/ECB/PKCS7 in c and java is not same

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, aes, pkcs#7

Hi i am using AES/ECB/PKCS7 mode for encryption, individually in c& java, encryption & decryption working fine.  But  in c encrypted data is not same as encrypted data in java...

I am posting my code  in  C language and java. I need Encryption in c and Decryption  in java. Please assist me c code for aes/ecb/pkcs7 is correct ??.. I am using openssl

C code:

```c
int Secure_encrypt(unsigned char *in, int inlen, unsigned char *out,int *outlen)
{
    int tmplen;
    // Key is 256 and is fixed.
    unsigned char key[256] =
    {   0x21,0x0a,0x03,0x23,0x45,0x29,0x78,0x12,0x35,0x45,0x67,0x78,0x21,0x13,
        0x34,0x56,0x67,0x45,0x12,0x89,0x38,0x0e,0xa0,0x15,0x21,
        0x0a,0x03,0x23,0x45,0x0b,0x15,0x0c
    };
    unsigned char *iv=0;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX x;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&x);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(&x,1); // 1- padding, 0 - No Padding
    if (!EVP_EncryptInit_ex(&x, EVP_aes_256_ecb(), 0, key, iv))
    {
        //printf("\n ERROR!! \n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (!EVP_EncryptUpdate(&x, out, outlen,(const unsigned char*) in, inlen))
    {
        //printf("\n ERROR!! \n");
        return -2;
    }
    if (!EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(&x,out + *outlen,&tmplen)) {
        //printf("\n ERROR!! \n");
        return -3;
    }
    *outlen += tmplen;
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf ("AES encrypted data %d len\n", *outlen);
    print_data (out, *outlen);
#endif
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&x);
    return 0;

}



/*AES DECRYPTION */
AES Decryption



int Secure_decrypt(unsigned char *in, int inlen, unsigned char *out,int *outlen)
{
    int tmplen;
    unsigned char *iv=0;
    unsigned char key[256]
    //AES/ECB/PKCS7 Padding
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX x;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&x);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(&x,1); // 1- padding, 0 - No Padding
    if (!EVP_DecryptInit_ex(&x, EVP_aes_256_ecb(), 0, key, iv)) {
        //printf("\n ERROR!! \n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (!EVP_DecryptUpdate(&x, out, outlen,(const unsigned char*) in, inlen))
    {
        //printf("\n ERROR!! \n");
        return -2;
    }
    if (!EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(&x,out + *outlen,&tmplen)) {
        //printf("\n ERROR!! \n");
        return -3;
    }
    *outlen += tmplen;

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf ("AES encrypted data %d len \n", *outlen);
    print_data (out, *outlen);
#endif
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&x);
    return 0;
}
```

Java code:

```java
import java.security.Security;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

public class doThis {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        String strDataToEncrypt = "Testing Encryption";
        byte[] byteDataToTransmit = strDataToEncrypt.getBytes();
        //41 6E 6B 61 72 61 6F 20 49 74 74 61 64 69
        //byte[] byteDataToTransmit = new byte []
        {
            0x41,0x6E,0x6B,0x61,0x72,0x61,0x6F,0x20,0x49,0x74,0x74,0x61,0x64,0x69
        };
        try {

            byte [] keyBytes= new byte [] {0x21,0x0a,0x03,0x23,0x45,0x29,0x78,0x12,0x35,
                                           0x45,0x67,0x78,0x21,0x13,0x34,

                                           0x56,0x67,0x45,0x12,0x9,0x38,0x0e,0x20,
                                           0x15,0x21,0x0a,0x03,0x23,0x45,0x0b,0x15,0x0c
                                          };

            byte[] encrypted= aesEncrypt(byteDataToTransmit,keyBytes);

            System.out.println("\n AES Encrypted Data is  "+new String (encrypted));

            byte [] byteDecrypt=aesDecrypt(bytestrEncrypt, keyBytes);
            System.out.println("\n AES Decrypted Data is"+byteDecrypt);
            // byte [] byteDecrypt=aesDecrypt(encrypted , keyBytes);

            //System.out.println("\n AES Decrypted Data is"+new String(byteDecrypt));
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            System.out.println(" Exception caught " + exp);
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static byte[] aesEncrypt(byte[] original, byte[] key)
    {
        try
        {
            SecretKeySpec keySpec = null;
            Cipher cipher = null;
            {
                keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
                cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec); // encryption
            }
            return cipher.doFinal(original);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //  Logger.e(e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static byte[] aesDecrypt(byte[] encrypted, byte[] key)
    {
        try
        {
            SecretKeySpec keySpec = null;
            Cipher cipher = null;

            {
                keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding");

                cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
            }

            System.out.println("In Decryprion \n"+ new String (encrypted));
            return cipher.doFinal(encrypted);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //  Logger.e(e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the output is not the same? Using new String(encrypted) and String.getBytes() methods without specifying the text encoding can give unpredictable results, so you'd be better off converting the byte[] to hexadecimal or Base64 somehow before printing.

Comment: Please format your code yourself. I've used `astyle` on your code. Are you sure that the keyspec part compiles with `"AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding"`? You should not require BouncyCastle to perform ECB AES operations by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least your handling of the returned amount of data is off. Check your buffer handling! Furthermore, in Java you use `new String (encrypted)` instead of converting the byte array to hexadecimals.